# using config files with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm creating a angular app that talks to a node backend express application and using a config file to set env variables in my node app I can access my config file like this:

**index.js**

```
  var port = config.get("server:port");
  var server = app.listen(port, function() {});
```

My config file looks like this:

**app.config.js**

```
    module.exports =
    {
"server":{
    "host":"localhost",
    "port":3000
  },
      "mongodb": "",

      "redis": {
        "loadBalancerInstance": {
          "host": "server",
          "port": {
            "default": "6379"
          }
        }
      },
      "elastic": {
        "server": "server",
        "port": "9200",
        "user":"foo",
        "password":"bar"
      },
      "log": {
        "level": "info",
        "filename": "",
        "console": true,
        "logio": {
          "port": "28777",
          "node_name": "this-server-name",
          "host": "server"
        }
      }
    };
```

I have statically defined the route/port to a backend

**datafactory.js**

```
angular.module('dashboard.factories')
  .factory('DataFactory', function($http, $q, FormatFactory) {
    var backend = function(apiEndPoint, clientKey) {
      clientKey = clientKey || "";
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get("http://localhost:3000/<-(pull this from config file)" + apiEndPoint + "/" + clientKey)
```

My question is how can I access app.config.js within angular and dynamically set host/port within my angular service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you're stuck on using the same configuration file that your node server uses, you'll have to make the .js file available to a GET request from your app, which you'll then have to parse out the string into JSON.

Edit:
You're going to have to have two configuration files, one available to your node server, and one for your angular app. Now, if you want the source to be one file, you could build that into your build process - if you use something like gulp or grunt, this would be reasonably easy. It could take the singular config file and build two files - the node server config file, and an angular module (I would suggest a constant or value) that you could inject into your data services.

Comment: how would you do a get request before you know which port the backend is running on?

Comment: sounds like you've got a problem if you can't access the config file without knowing the contents of the config file.

Comment: is there not a way to use a get require equivalent on the frontend and just import the config file like i do with the backend

Comment: a simple google search leads me to believe it would: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/angularjs-browserify/

Comment: came across this as well didn't know if it was common/best practices but thanks i think this will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving the config file at `localhost:3000/config`, you can do this:

```
angular.module('dashboard.factories')
.factory('DataFactory', function($http, $q, FormatFactory) {
    $http.get('localhost:3000/config')
    .success(function(config) {
        $http.get(config.server.host + ":" + config.server.port)
        // whatever you want here
    });
});
```

Comment: The config file OP provided in the question is not valid JSON.